# PHP if I use requre() inside of a function is that file before calling the function?

Tags: php, function, include, require

If a file is included or required inside a function is it loaded if the function is not invoked? Example:

page.php

```
<?php
require('functions.php');
a();
?>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
function a(){
    require('a.php');
}
function b(){
    require('b.php');
}
function c(){
    include('c.php');
}
?>
```

Are b.php or c.php loaded?

Comment: If you use require() inside a function, the "globals" in the file will be local to the function.

Comment: Another question: with your test code totally ready to go... You didn't think of running it and get the answer immediately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No they aren't loaded unless you actually call the functions `b()` and `c()`.

The code inside `b.php` and `c.php` will also be local to the functions they are included in.  That is any variables they define won't be available outside of `b()` or `c()` respectively.

See [PHP: include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info about locality.

Comment: @drer010, your statement "That is ... functions they define won't be available outside of b() or c() respectively." is _not true_!! See [User-defined functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) - "All functions and classes in PHP have the global scope - they can be called outside a function even if they were defined inside and vice versa."  That is once the function of or logical path containing the function definition is executed, the function is then available globally.

Answer (score 1):

Simply: No. If the `require` or `include` is in a function, it *will not* be invoked if the function is not executed.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested it out on my server.  Any function that is not called will not fire.

Answer (score 0):

How this works is bit more complicated than drew010's answer.  As this is misleading, I felt that I should clarify this.  Consider this test case:

> **main.php**

```
<?php
require('/tmp/functions.php');
echo "exists=",function_exists('a1'),"\n";
a();
echo "exists=",function_exists('a1'),"\n";
a1();
?>
```

> **functions.php**

```
<?php
function a(){
    require('a1.php');
}
```

> **a1.php**

This produces as output:

```
exists=
exists=1
Hello World
```

In other words `a1()`does not exist until `a()` is called but it is then available globally.  Consider another example:

```
<?php
$a=false;
if( $a ){
    function x() {return 1;}
} else {
    function x() {return 2;}
}
echo x();
```

This again is perfectly valid and displays `2`.  If `$a` had been set to **true** then the answer would be `1`, and if you do a VLD of this code, you can see why.  The two functions emit the opcode sequences that you would expect, but are given non-callable names based on the path of the script file (in my case `%00x%2Ftmp%2Fy.php0x7fb364a1a03`and `%00x%2Ftmp%2Fy.php0x7fb364a1a06`)  The calling code generates a

```
ZEND_DECLARE_FUNCTION    '%00x%2Ftmp%2Fy.php0x7fb364a1a033', 'x'
```

at the path point where the first declaration is make.  This makes the function available as `x()` and a similar **ZEND_DECLARE_FUNCTION** makes the the second function available as `x()` on the alternative path.

Exactly the same mechanism works for classes, though in this case a **ZEND_DECLARE_CLASS** is invoke to bind the internal class name to its public alias.